# Clear Set TimeOut Javascript

Tags: javascript, timeout, set

I am creating Tabs in javascript in my ASP.Net web site. Say Tab 1 Tab 2--- Tab 10.
 When I click on Tab 1 it shows some data and I call setTimeout function that keeps refreshing the Tab 1 data. My problem is when i switch to other tabs the settimeout function still keep running in the background, that i don't want. How can i stop this on moving to other tabs.

Thanks

Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) function. Example:

```
var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function() {
    // ...
}, 5000);
```

and later you could:

```
window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
```

There are also the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setinterval)/[clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearinterval) methods which could be used. Contrary to `setTimeout`, the `setInterval` function executes the callback multiple times until cleared. A similar behavior could be achieved with `setTimeout` by recursively calling the callback.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I tried this but in my case when i again come on Tab 1 then SetTimeout function throws an error "Invalid Parameters". Is it so that once time out is cleared out we can not re call settimeout?

Comment: @Vivek, normally there shouldn't be any problems of reassigning the setTimeout. Unfortunately as you haven't shown any code I am unable to provide you with more help.